# Specify max_bandwidth or TransferConfig for boto3 s3 upload_part

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

The `upload_file` method allows you to specify `max_bandwidth` using the `boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig` object: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3.html

The `upload_part` method, however, does not seem to allow a `TransferConfig`. You get the following error when trying to use one:

```
*** botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "config", must be one of: Body, Bucket, ContentLength, ContentMD5, Key, PartNumber, UploadId, SSECustomerAlgorithm, SSECustomerKey, SSECustomerKeyMD5, RequestPayer, ExpectedBucketOwner
```

Is there some way to limit upload bandwidth when performing a MultiPartUpload with `boto3`? Perhaps setting some property on the `s3` `client` object?

NB: I know you can set `multipart_threshold` in a `TransferConfig` and use `upload_file`, but that strategy does not allow you to pickup resume transfers where you left off (if your connection dies after uploading 20 of 30 parts and you retry, it will re-upload the first 20 again).

**I want to use `upload_part` so I can manually check which parts have already been uploaded and only upload those parts I need to (so that if my connection drops and the upload fails after uploading 20 of 30 parts, I can just upload the last 10 parts when I retry instead of uploading the first 20 again).**

Here is my multipart uploader with resume failures for reference (the stuff about `project` is specific to my application, but hopefully code makes sense and is helpful):

```py
class MultipartUpload:
    def __init__(self, client, project, local_file):
        self.client = client
        self.project = project
        self.local_file = local_file
        self.parts = []
        self.debug = False

    def orphan(self):
        project_prefix = _project_prefix(self.project)
        key = self.local_file.key

        uploads = self.client.list_multipart_uploads(
            Bucket=S3_BUCKET, Prefix=project_prefix
        )
        if "Uploads" not in uploads:
            self._debug("No 'Uploads' key.")
            return None

        # find those that match the file
        orphans = [u for u in uploads["Uploads"] if u["Key"] == key]

        # TODO:: also COMPARE md5 / etag
        if len(orphans) == 0:
            self._debug("No matching orphans.")
            return None

        # TODO: elect the best orphan if there is more than one:
        return orphans[0]

    def upload(self):
        upload = self.orphan()

        uploaded_parts = []

        if upload:
            upload_id = upload["UploadId"]
            resp = self.list_parts(upload_id)
            uploaded_parts = resp.get("Parts", [])
        else:
            upload = self.create_upload()
            upload_id = upload["UploadId"]
            uploaded_parts = []

        self._debug(
            "filesize: {}mb chunksize: {}mb num_parts: {}".format(
                self.local_file.size / 1024 / 2024,
                self.local_file.chunksize / 1024 / 1024,
                self.local_file.num_parts,
            )
        )

        uploaded_part_nums = set([p["PartNumber"] for p in uploaded_parts])
        checksums = []
        bytes_uploaded = 0
        for part in self.local_file.parts():
            part_num = part.part_num
            chunk = part.bytes
            chunksize = part.size
            bytes_uploaded = bytes_uploaded + chunksize
            checksums.append(part.checksum)

            progress_msg = "{}/{} {}mb chunks || {}mb of {}mb || {}%".format(
                part_num,
                self.local_file.num_parts,
                int(chunksize / 1024 / 1024),
                int(bytes_uploaded / 1024 / 1024),
                int(self.local_file.size / 1024 / 1024),
                int(100 * bytes_uploaded / self.local_file.size),
            )

            # continue if part already uploaded
            if part_num in uploaded_part_nums:
                self._write(f"[already uploaded]: {progress_msg}")
                continue

            self._write(f"[uploading ......]: {progress_msg}")

            self.client.upload_part(
                Body=chunk,
                Bucket=S3_BUCKET,
                Key=self.local_file.key,
                UploadId=upload_id,
                PartNumber=part_num,
            )
        self.finalize(upload_id, checksums)

    def _debug(self, message):
        if self.debug:
            print("{}: {}".format(self.local_file.local_path, message))

    def _write(self, message):
        msg = "UPLOADING: %s: %s" % (
            self.local_file.local_path,
            message,
        )
        _print_over_same_line(msg)
        # sys.stdout.write("\r%s" % msg)
        # sys.stdout.flush()

    def list_parts(self, upload_id):
        resp = self.client.list_parts(
            UploadId=upload_id, Bucket=S3_BUCKET, Key=self.local_file.key
        )
        if "Parts" not in resp:
            self._debug("No 'Parts' uploaded.")
        return resp

    def create_upload(self):
        resp = self.client.create_multipart_upload(
            Bucket=S3_BUCKET,
            ContentType=self.local_file.mime_type,
            Key=self.local_file.key,
        )
        upload_id = resp.get("UploadId")
        self._debug(f"Created multipart upload_id:{upload_id}")
        return resp

    def _checksums(self):
        checksums = []
        for part in self.local_file.parts():
            checksums.append(part.checksum)
        return checksums

    def finalize(self, upload_id, checksums=None):
        # recompute the parts / etags
        if checksums is None:
            checksums = self._checksums()

        self._write("[finalizing {} parts]: ".format(len(checksums)))
        resp = self.client.complete_multipart_upload(
            Bucket=S3_BUCKET,
            Key=self.local_file.key,
            UploadId=upload_id,
            MultipartUpload={"Parts": checksums},
        )
        print("")  # clear terminal
        if 200 != resp.get("ResponseMetadata", {}).get("HTTPStatusCode"):
            print(resp)
            raise Exception


def _upload(client, project, local_file, max_bandwidth_mb=None):
    if local_file.size < AWS_MIN_CHUNKSIZE:
        x = {}
        # x["MetaData"] = {"Content-MD5": local_file.etag}
        if local_file.mime_type:
            x["ContentType"] = local_file.mime_type
            # , "ETag": local_file.etag
        client.upload_file(
            local_file.local_path,
            S3_BUCKET,
            local_file.key,
            # Config=_transfer_config(max_bandwidth_mb, upload_file=local_file),
            # Callback=ProgressPercentage(local_file.local_path, local_file.size),
            ExtraArgs=x,
        )
        # add a newline since we have been flushing stdout:
        # print("")
    else:
        mu = MultipartUpload(client, project, local_file)
        mu.upload()
```

Comment: It's approaching an implementation detail, but `max_bandwidth` is implemented by controlling how fast the transfer manager reads from the source stream.  So, no component downstream of the part that does the `read()` calls has any concept of limiting bandwidth, including `upload_part`. In other words, you'll need to limit the bandwidth yourself.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. Will add manual implementation link diff.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Anon Coward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75843297/specify-max-bandwidth-or-transferconfig-for-boto3-s3-upload-part?noredirect=1#comment133781266_75843297) comment, it sounds like this needs to be done manually.

Here is the diff of how I ended up adding this myself:
https://github.com/kortina/sq/commit/d27db3a28b3c44b36682b31ccc9d72258236d04b